# DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I have this code in a class:

```
...
$document = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8');
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'); //this fix problems with cyrilic text
if ( !@$document->loadHtml( $content ) )
    return false;
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $document );
$node_list = $xpath->query( $this->target->query_name() ); // getting warning here
...
```

The code of query_name method (located in other class and file) is:

```
public function query_name( $if_arg_needed = "" ){
    return "//*/*[@class=\'product_name\']";
}
```

Both files containing my classes are in utf-8.
Why i'm getting the warning:
    Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in ...

This code works fine:

```
...
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $document );
$tempStr = "//*/*[@class=\'product_name\']";
$node_list = $xpath->query( $tempStr );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the xpath like this:

`$tempStr = "//*[@class='product_name']";`

or

`$tempStr = '//*[@class="product_name"]';`

Comment: OMG! Those slashes!!! I've even forgotten why i placed them there. Thanks you very much lauda!